how to minimize the space between two side-by-side examples?
For the following two examples, I would like to first reduce spaces between a/b and examples, and then make the two examples occur in one line (try to save more space for a conference abstract). Could anyone offer some help here?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times} %Times New Roman Font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%denotation brackets for semantics

%packages for linguistic examples
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{
    aboveglftskip = -.08cm,
    aboveexskip = 0 pt,
    belowexskip = 0 pt,
    belowpreambleskip = 3 pt,
    extraglskip = 0 pt,
    everygla=,
    interpartskip= 2 pt
    %   numoffset=\parindent
}

\begin{document}
\ex[glhangstyle=none, glwidth=\textwidth]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth} % Adjusted width
a. \quad
$\lsem \textit{\$} \rsem$\textsuperscript{$c$} = $\lambda$\textit{f}\textsubscript{$vt$}$\lambda$$\sigma$.$\sigma$ $\sqsubseteq$ \{S $\subseteq$ \textit{f} : $\exists$$s$ $\in$ $f$. ($S$ = $s$\textsuperscript{–$\zeta$})\}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth} % Adjusted width
b. \quad
$\lsem \textnormal{AP} \rsem$\textsuperscript{$c$} = $\lambda$$\sigma$.$\sigma$ $\sqsubseteq$ $Dom$($\langle$$D$\textsubscript{\textsuperscript{–}$H$}, $\succeq$\textsubscript{\textsuperscript{–}$H$} $\rangle$) \& $\nearrow$($\sigma$) 
\end{minipage}
\xe


\end{document}




You're explicitly adding space after a. and b. with the \quad. Removing it helps a little, but really those expressions are just too long to fit on a single line as is. You can make them fit by resizing the expressions with either \resizebox or \scalebox from the graphicx package. \resizebox can scale its contents such that they occupy a specified width, while \scalebox applies a fixed scaling factor.
Here's your code again with additional versions added to demonstrate all of the above. I also cleaned up the expressions so that they're not going in and out of math mode unnecessarily.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times} %Times New Roman Font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%denotation brackets for semantics

%packages for linguistic examples
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{
    aboveglftskip = -.08cm,
    aboveexskip = 0 pt,
    belowexskip = 0 pt,
    belowpreambleskip = 3 pt,
    extraglskip = 0 pt,
    everygla=,
    interpartskip= 2 pt
    %   numoffset=\parindent
}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Original examples
\ex[glhangstyle=none, glwidth=\textwidth]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth} % Adjusted width
    a. \quad
    $\lsem \textit{\$} \rsem$\textsuperscript{$c$} = $\lambda$\textit{f}\textsubscript{$vt$}$\lambda$$\sigma$.$\sigma$ $\sqsubseteq$ \{S $\subseteq$ \textit{f} : $\exists$$s$ $\in$ $f$. ($S$ = $s$\textsuperscript{–$\zeta$})\}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth} % Adjusted width
    b. \quad
    $\lsem \textnormal{AP} \rsem$\textsuperscript{$c$} = $\lambda$$\sigma$.$\sigma$ $\sqsubseteq$ $Dom$($\langle$$D$\textsubscript{\textsuperscript{–}$H$}, $\succeq$\textsubscript{\textsuperscript{–}$H$} $\rangle$) \& $\nearrow$($\sigma$) 
\end{minipage}
\xe
\\
Stay in math mode, remove \texttt{\string\quad} space after a. and b.:
\ex[glhangstyle=none, glwidth=\textwidth]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth} % Adjusted width
    a.
    $\lsem \textit{\$} \rsem^c = \lambda f_{vt} \lambda \sigma . \sigma \sqsubseteq \{\text{S} \subseteq f : \exists s \in f. (S = s^{-\zeta})\}$
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth} % Adjusted width
    b.
    $\lsem \text{AP} \rsem^c = \lambda \sigma . \sigma \sqsubseteq Dom(\langle D_{^{-}H}, \succeq_{^{-}H} \rangle) \text{\&} \nearrow (\sigma)$
\end{minipage}
\xe
\\
Use \texttt{\string\resizebox} so that each example fits within a specified width:
\ex[glhangstyle=none, glwidth=\textwidth]
a.
\resizebox{0.45\linewidth}{!}{
    $\lsem \textit{\$} \rsem^c = \lambda f_{vt} \lambda \sigma . \sigma \sqsubseteq \{\text{S} \subseteq f : \exists s \in f. (S = s^{-\zeta})\}$
}
\, % add some separation between sub-examples
b.
\resizebox{0.43\linewidth}{!}{
    $\lsem \text{AP} \rsem^c = \lambda \sigma . \sigma \sqsubseteq Dom(\langle D_{^{-}H}, \succeq_{^{-}H} \rangle) \text{\&} \nearrow (\sigma)$
}
\xe
\\
Use \texttt{\string\scalebox} so that the same scaling is applied to both examples:
\ex[glhangstyle=none, glwidth=\textwidth]
a.
\scalebox{0.94}{
    $\lsem \textit{\$} \rsem^c = \lambda f_{vt} \lambda \sigma . \sigma \sqsubseteq \{\text{S} \subseteq f : \exists s \in f. (S = s^{-\zeta})\}$
}
\, % add some separation between sub-examples
b.
\scalebox{0.94}{
    $\lsem \text{AP} \rsem^c = \lambda \sigma . \sigma \sqsubseteq Dom(\langle D_{^{-}H}, \succeq_{^{-}H} \rangle) \text{\&} \nearrow (\sigma)$
}
\xe

\end{document}

This gives the following output:

The examples show output from

your original code
removing the \quad spaces and cleaning up the expressions as described above
changes in (2) and using \resizebox to specify a width for each sub-example
changes in (2) and using \scalebox to apply the same scaling to both sub-examples

Examples (2) and (3) also add a small space between the sub-examples so that they don't run together.
